# Refactoring existing pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I am using Factory Pattern in order to initialize objects:

```
public class Factory
{
    @Autowired
    private HandlerOne handlerOne;
    @Autowired
    private HandlerTwo handlerTwo;

    public <T extends Handler> T createHandler(Class<T> type) {
        switch(type.getSimpleName()){
            case "HandlerOne":
                return type.cast(handlerOne.handle());
    }
}
```

And this is how I use the factory itself:

```
handlerFactory.createHandler(HandlerOne.class);
```

All the Handlers are located in a separate package called `com.mydomain.project.Handlers`

As you can see, if there are X handler implementations, I'll need to create X variables inside the factory and I think this is bad. Is there an existing pattern I can apply in order to make this process easier?

Comment: The responsibility of a factory pattern is to construct new instances. You do not construct new instances, you only initialize them. The factory pattern is abused here because the factory creates nothing. **I'll need to create X variables inside the factory and I think this is bad.**, it is a pattern violation because you create nothing. What do you like to do, initialize or create?

Comment: @PeterRader the .handle() method produces a new object(EventHandlerOne). There's HandlerOne and EventHandlerOne which are two totally different objects.

Comment: Aha! Your Factory-class creates nothing, it is the the handle-method who creates instances. Therefore the handle-method fullifies the `factory method pattern`. Your factory is not a real factory.

Comment: do all Handler have a "handle()" method to instantiate a new one ? If yes, is it under a common interface ?

Comment: @Asoub correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can inject all beans of certain type as a list:

```
public class Factory
{
    @Autowired
    private List<? extends Handler> handlerList; 

    public <T extends Handler> T createHandler(Class<T> type) {
        for(Handler handler : handlerList) {
            if (type.getSimpleName().equals(handler.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
                return handler;
            }
        }

        return ...; //some default value
    }
}
```